# Long key press in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When pressing a key for a few second, the browser (Google Chrome) shows a little popup over the letter suggesting another characters. Those values (º, ń...) are allowed on what I'm doing but I don't wan't that to appear...

[image]

[Click here if the gif doesn't reproduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBrJo.gif)

Is there a way to prevent that little pop up? Using javascript or html attribute (like autocorrect=off)?

Comment: Interesting - my Chrome doesn't do that.  How did you make it do it?

Comment: Oops... Is a Mac thing. I just tried using it on another input field (spotlight). I'm embarrassed

Comment: No problem!  (Shame - it's a feature I'd like to have!)